# Is it possible to reliably infer the anthropogenic contribution to the post-industrial rise in $\ce{CO2}$ from $^{14}\ce{C}$ observations?

Tags: climate-change, carbon-cycle, anthropogenic

There have been several papers [failures of the review process] that have argued that the post-industrial rise in atmospheric $\ce{CO2}$ is primarily a natural phenomenon, or have sought to minimise the anthropogenic contribution.  This is a recent example:

> K. Skrable, G. Chabot and Clayton French, "World Atmospheric CO2, Its
> 14C Specific Activity, Non-fossil Component, Anthropogenic Fossil
> Component, and Emissions (1750–2018)", Health Physics: February 2022 -
> Volume 122 - Issue 2 - p 291-305 doi: [10.1097/HP.0000000000001485](https://dx.doi.org/10.1097/HP.0000000000001485)
>
> **Abstract**
>
> After 1750 and the onset of the industrial revolution, the
> anthropogenic fossil component and the non-fossil component in the
> total atmospheric CO2 concentration, C(t), began to increase. Despite
> the lack of knowledge of these two components, claims that all or most
> of the increase in C(t) since 1800 has been due to the anthropogenic
> fossil component have continued since they began in 1960 with “Keeling
> Curve: Increase in CO2 from burning fossil fuel.” Data and plots of
> annual anthropogenic fossil CO2 emissions and concentrations, C(t),
> published by the Energy Information Administration, are expanded in
> this paper. Additions include annual mean values in 1750 through 2018
> of the 14C specific activity, concentrations of the two components,
> and their changes from values in 1750. The specific activity of 14C in
> the atmosphere gets reduced by a dilution effect when fossil CO2,
> which is devoid of 14C, enters the atmosphere. We have used the
> results of this effect to quantify the two components. All results
> covering the period from 1750 through 2018 are listed in a table and
> plotted in figures. These results negate claims that the increase in
> C(t) since 1800 has been dominated by the increase of the
> anthropogenic fossil component. We determined that in 2018,
> atmospheric anthropogenic fossil CO2 represented 23% of the total
> emissions since 1750 with the remaining 77% in the exchange
> reservoirs. Our results show that the percentage of the total CO2 due
> to the use of fossil fuels from 1750 to 2018 increased from 0% in 1750
> to 12% in 2018, much too low to be the cause of global warming.

---

Fossil $\ce{CO2}$ will be essentially depleted of $^{14}\ce{C}$ as it has been in the lithosphere for millions of years, far longer than the half-life of $^{14}\ce{C}$, so obviously fossil fuel emissions will have had an effect on the *relative* concentrations of 14C in the atmosphere.  However, that is likely obscured by the $^{14}\ce{C}$ from nuclear testing in the 1950s and 60s.  Also when $^{14}\ce{C}$ is removed from the atmosphere, the amount of CO2 has not been reduced, it is just that the $^{14}\ce{C}$ from the atmosphere has been exchanged with $\ce{C}$ from the other reservoirs, at the mixing ratio found in those reservoirs.  This means it is more informative of the residence time (the average time a molecule of CO2 remains in the atmosphere before being exchanged) than the adjustment time (the time scale on which atmospheric $\ce{CO2}$ decays towards it's equilibrium value).

$\color{red}{\star}$ Is it possible to reliably infer the anthropogenic contribution to the post-industrial rise in atmospheric $\ce{CO2}$ from $^{14}\ce{C}$ observations?

A reference to a paper where this is demonstrated would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

The NOAA has used carbon-14 to identify *local sources* of anthropogenic carbon dioxide, which would suffer less interference from  factors acting elsewhere around the globe, such as nuclear testing. The map below, showing yellow and red areas where the near-surface atmosphere is depleted of carbon-14, matches with the most densely populated and heavily industrialized areas of North America.

[Reference and figure source](https://research.noaa.gov/article/ArtMID/587/ArticleID/2631/Fingerprinting-fossil-fuel-emissions-with-carbon-14)

[image]

Comment: Thanks that looks interesting, but it is just showing the locations of anthropogenic sources, rather than the anthropogenic contribution to the post-industrial rise in CO2 (which is not the same as the proportion of CO2 directly from anthropogenic sources, because of the large exchange fluxes between reservoirs).